# Access Neo4J with public url

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, neo4j

Hi I am new to Neo4J i am searching from 2 days for access Neo4J every one through URL of public.
In settings of neo4j configuration file some modifications i done those are

```
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474
```

I got the access for only with in router level means ip4 address level i got but i want to give access to every one.

Because i am using Asp.MVC  with script and Neo4jAPI. I installed Neo4j in separate server and app published in separate server i want access the Neo4JAPI

Comment: well you need to set up a neo4j on a machine with a external public IP, so your app can connect to your neo4j from anywhere

Comment: how to connect external public IP, i tried but not getting in place url http://*My public ip:7474/  getting This site can’t be reached

Answer (score 0):

Setting an external public IP is a function of the router managing the connections. If this is a corporate setup, ask the administrator. If this is a personal setup, you will need to do a bunch of things, such as:

- Setup a local HTTP server
- Allow inbound traffic on port 80
- Setup a DNS service
- Setup an SSH server
- Forward requests on your router to your computer for different ports

This is highly risky and you could be open to problems if you're not careful. A better approach would be to use a public service like AWS to host your application.